# Converting String[] to String in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

The objective: Create a program that responds to the "sysout" of the first RNG produced results.

The last two lines are the problematic lines.

The code thus far:

```
    import java.util.Random;

public class Tutorials {

public static void main(String[] args) {
String[] test = new String [3];
test[0]= "go";
test[1] = "stop";
test [2] = "slow";
System.out.println(test [new Random ().nextInt(test.length)]);
if (test="stop") { System.out.println("wait 3 seconds");}   
}

}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to boolean
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[]

 at Tutorials.main(Tutorials.java:11)
"

Comment: ```if (test="stop")``` is not testing for anything.

Comment: `if (test="stop")` assigns a String to a String array and you expect it to return a boolean.

Comment: How would I work around that? If I wish to use the results for the next step?

Comment: test is an array, so test = "stop" won't work for 2 reasons.  1) = is an assignment.  You want == to compare.  2) test is an array, so you need an array index like test[1] == "stop"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign a String to String array in this line `if (test="stop")`. To perform the check it needs to be `==` not `=`. But when doing String comparision try to use `.equals()` instead of the `==` operator, [more info about == vs .equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520464/1754020)

## Solution

```
public class Tutorials {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String[] test = {"go", "stop", "slow"};
       String result = test [new Random().nextInt(test.length)];
       System.out.println(result);

       if (result.equals("stop")) { 
         System.out.println("wait 3 seconds");
       }   
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Miguel.P No probem! If you feel this answer solved your question please accept. Also you can initialize array in one line like the example provided.